# How to disallow character on with ZF2 Form Validator

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-form

I would like to disallow people to writing character "#" on my input how can I achieve it ?

Comment: How about RegEx validator class with a pattern like `[^#]` (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.validator.set.html#regex)? What have you tried? Maybe you could just filter that input field instead of validating it? Some more info would be useful.

Comment: Regex is good idea but when i'm using this pattern : [^#] the form is never valid, with or without #.

Comment: Answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704061/php-reverse-preg-match this pattern working : /^(?:(?!#).)*$/i

Answer (score 1):

As @guessimtoolate suggested, since if you want to disallow only the sharp-character, then it's best to simply filter it out. Filters are run before Validation, therefore your workflow is like this:

- Get Field Value
- Remove all occurences of the character `#`
- Validate your field using your attached validators

The Filter you wanna be using is the [`Zend\Filter\PregReplace`](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.filter.set.html#pregreplace). In case you're providing your Filters/Validators via the provider-interface, then the array-notation should be the following (it's untested, so you may work around a little bit with it)

```
'filters' => array(
    array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\PregReplace', 'options' => array(
       'pattern'     => '/#/',
       'replacement' => ''
    )
)
```