# Match not having .php using regular expressions

Tags: regex

With regular expressions, how do I match anything **not** having:

```
.php
```

exactly? I tried:

```
^[^\.php]+$
```

But this seems to be match **not** `.` or `p` or `h` or `p`.

Comment: Seems to be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5704061/php-reverse-preg-match

Comment: Humm, can't get it working. Tried `^(?!(\.php$))`.

Comment: ... which is not like in the example.
That works:
$filter = ".php$";
$text = "stuff.php3";
if (preg_match("/^(?:(?!" . $filter . ").)*$/i", $text)) { echo "yeahhh"; }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `negative lookahead` in your regex to check whether there is any `.php` is available or not.

```
$text = 'some php text';
if(preg_match("/^(?!.*\.php)(.*)$/", $text, $m)){
    print_r($m[1]);
}
```

`^` is the beginning of the string.

`(?!.*\.php)` is checking if there is no `.php` in upfront.

And `(.*)$` is capturing everything till the end.